# What are the recomended clothes to use with fortify alchemy?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How can I save my coins when enchanting with the fortify alchemy spell as described [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Enchanting_%28Skyrim%29)? Does it make sense to use light leather clothes?

Comment: Every single one of these answers that doesn't suggest a Chef's Hat enchanted with Fortify Alchemy as mandatory is a failure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Choose lightweight equipment so you can carry it round with you.

Go to the clothes shop in Solitude for a full range of dresswear to choose from, including gloves and circlets and hats.

Saving your coins is irrelevant. Most clothing costs less than a single petty soul gem.

edit:

Following on from a good point about naming: you can use a "." full-stop at the start of the name. All symbols are place in the inventory first. I have mine named like:

.Alchemist's Cowl
.Alchemist's Safety Gloves
.Forgemaster's Ovenmitts
.Forgemaster's Heatproof Apron

etc...

Comment: That naming tip is brilliant! I should have thought of that on my own since I use that in Windows Explorer/Outlook folder naming!

Answer (score 5):

I just want to add to the other comments, be sure to name them otherwise things get really confusing. And don't name them hat of alchemy. Name it Alchemy hat, alchemy gloves, alchemy amulet etc so that when you equip them they're all in the same place. I wish I could name potions. Try my [potion generator](http://rp.eliteskills.com/skyrim.html).

Comment: i agree i name mine +30% a-w & alc ring and such

Answer (score 3):

Enchantments in Skyrim are the same, no matter what item you put them on (for a given skill level, soul size, and perks known).

This means enchanting a pair of Leather Bracers with "Fortify Smithing" is just as effective as enchanting a pair of Daedric Gauntlets with the same effect.

This is different from Oblivion, where item choice mattered, mostly because many pieces of clothing took up multiple "slots" on the character's body, and if you weren't careful, you could wind up with fewer enchants than if you had worn armor.

Comment: Just remember that not all items accept all enchantments. Boots I find are the most annoying in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind abusing a glitch, you can wear a circlet and a forsworn helmet simultaneously, granting you 5 total items boosting your alchemy stat. Sadly, not possible with the chef hat :(

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it but I noticed that forsworn helmet can wear with the otar mask.

Answer (score 1):

4 items in apparel for alchemy-i personally use...

gloves  -weight .5

hat     -weight .5

ring    -weight .3

necklace-weight .5

now i have all these items Dual enchanted 30% Smithing/Alchemy 
" all except the Hat which won't take smithing,i singled with Alchemy and added smithing
to my normal armor along with magika regeneration "
saving money by Dual enchanting-saving weight by using the items i listed above.
the price of the item from the crappiest ring to the most expensive sadly has not
beneficial effect.
hoped this helped

Comment: I'm not that experienced yet I get only 21% Smithing and Alchemy even with helmet exploit. I wonder when I hit the armor and weapon cap?!

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the Krosis mask at Shearpoint, which adds 20 points to alchemy when worn.

Combined with the other alchemy-enchanted apparel that you've made, you can make the strongest enchanting potion in the game to create more powerful alchemy apparel. After donning these and the Krosis mask, make even stronger enchanting potions, which can be used to to create even stronger alchemy apparel and so on until you achieve extraordinarily high level enchanting potions, way stronger than the game gifts you. You have to keep changing into the ever more powerful alchemy apparel to keep upping the enchanting potion. Then use your ultra powerful enchanting potions to make smithing apparel that can be worn to improve armour and weapons 1000%+ when you go smithing.

You basically become invincible, but I would caution that the game becomes less interesting when there's no challenge.

Don't give Krosis to your familiar to carry for you. There is a bug where the item could disappear from their inventory. And don't sell it if you want to exploit the alchemy/enchanting loop. You need it to do that. It's possible to buy it back from the merchant you sold it to, or pickpocket it if you can't see it in their inventory during trade. But you have to remember who you sold it to! I forgot. :-(

Answer (score -1):

The fortify restoration pot loop is the most effective means of gear breaking in Skyrim.

Via that loop, not only can you make broken gear, but you can also power level really fast.
Given the fact that the effects of the pot don't always wear off immediately, you can spam this exploit in a nigh on infinite loop to level, then reset your alchemy craft level.

I spent less than 48 hours on my new khajit and she's already 189,nd that's with a lot of goofing off and not focusing on the task at hand. But with that loop comes an issue. You must be aware of over powering yourself. The highest boost you realistically want would be no more than about say 1300-1400. Higher than that, and your enchanting pots would crash the game. Trust me, I spent 3 hours last night ensuring that I had a moderate powered potion.

Also, instead of enchanting your gear for smithing, just craft several fort smith pots and use them to break your gear. Don't go over about 1600-1700 or you'll end up sending your gear into data underflow and that can end up allowing you to be one shot. Although you can use 2600-2900 fort smith pot on your gear. Data underflow on weapons doesn't determine you nearly as badly in that category.

Same for enchants on weapons. Overpowered ench pots are OK on weapons, because it doesn't crash the game. I put a lot of time into learning how to break the game XP. By the way, best enchants on weapons are chaos and soul trap or fiery soul trap if you've managed to find it. That's primarily due to the fact that the extra damage from chaos will hurt a lot even if you want to keep vanilla level damage on your weapons. Again, I know this from experience.

Base level hunter's bow can still almost one shot, if not one shot almost any dragon if you have ridiculous amounts of damage on your enchantments. Oh fortify archery with higher enchant pot doesn't break the game. I have over 1,000,000% archery on my helm. Didn't break the game. Quite lovely. Upgraded my bow, it does 122k damage, and with the helm it does over 1 billion. I one shot everything.

Oh, and take care not to use the fort resto pot with over enchanted gear on, can glitch and bring ench back down to regular ench levels.